# Fortigate 3800 and Juniper QFX 5200 40G connectivity

Tags: juniper, fortigate

We are planning to put a Juniper QFX 5200 series switch which has 40G QSFP+ ports in front of the firewall which has QSFP+ 40G ports. They should work well with the 3800 Firewall's QSFP+ 40G port right?

Actually my question is general. Irrespective device types and vendor, 40G QSFP+ will work across the devices right? So this will work without breakout cables and give 40G bandwidth on each link?

Comment: What type of optics are you using on each side? The most common one we use is the JNP-QSFP-40G-LX4 which shoots 1310nm over SM or OM3 MM (100m).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The thing to watch with 40G between devices is multi-mode fibre patch leads.

Unlike regular multi-mode SFP/SFP+ where you have only two cores of fibre which are crossed over between devices, multi-mode QSFPs connect to MTP cabling, which is 12 cores, of which, 4 will be active to achieve a 40Gbps interface.

When looking at your QFX or Fortigate QSFP with the "key" at the top, you will be presented with the following (T is Transmit and R is Receive):

```
         __________________    
 _______|       "key"      |__________
|                                    |
|[T][T][T][T][ ][ ][ ][ ][R][R][R][R]|
|1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

(apologies for woeful ASCII art)

If you are patching directly between both devices (i.e. no structured cabling), you will need a patch lead that maps cores 1-12, 2-11, 3-10, 4-9.

These patch leads are known as MTP Polarity B (essentially an MTP cross-over cable).

If you are using single-mode to connect the devices, then none of this will apply - your QSFP+ single-mode transceivers will present LC connectors, and regular OS1 patch-leads will work just fine.

Alternatively, you could also just use QFSP+ DACs (Direct-Attach Copper) which are pre-terminated.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Thanks it is helpful. But I read there is a LC connector in MMF transceivers as well. http://www.cables-solutions.com/what-is-the-difference-between-singlemode-qsfp-and-multimode-qsfp.html

Comment: Yes - these are 40Gbase-LX4 - instead of sending 4x 10Gbps lanes over 8 cores, they send 4x 10Gbps over CWDM (different wavelengths) over a single pair (thus only requiring LC connectors).  They are great if you have existing duplex multi-mode structured cabling, however they would be overkill if you are just going between two devices in the same rack.

Comment: Hi Benjamin: Over kill interms of cost?

Comment: Yes - especially if you are connecting within the same rack

Comment: Ok got it. They are with in the rack. I will check the MTP option. Thanks once again!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes they should work just fine as long as the proper optics and jumpers are used on each end.